# Gjs Gnome shell extension

Tags: gnome-shell

I have the following code

```
const session = new Soup.Session();
const message = Soup.Message.new('GET','https://www.example.com');
let _data = session.send(message, null);
const response_headers = message.get_response_headers();
```

After I run this code I get an error that function `message.get_response_headers()` doesn't exist.

I have imported all the required packages.

Comment: Not sure this programming question fits perfectly here, would seem like it's really better suited on stackoverflow.com. However, you will have to believe the error message: that function simply doesn't exist. So, barring any typos, the documentation you've been reading doesn't fit the version of whatever `Soup` is.